# Add droppable element with Mootools' drag&drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, mootools

here's my problem, I'm using mootools' Drag&Drop functionalities, it works great but i can't find a way to add new droppable element on the fly since the droppable element are defined when the draggables are.
Their is a method makedraggable that you can use to add draggable element but it has no equivalent for the droppables.

With jQuery, you set the draggable elements on one side and the droppable on the other, so you can do pretty much what you want.

Do you know a way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

in theory, you should be able to push elements to the `instance.droppables` collection.

```
var foo = new Drag.Move({
    droppables: document.getElements('div.dropHere'),
    ...
});


foo.droppables.push(document.id('newDropHere'));
// or... 
foo.droppables.include(element); // etc. all array/Elements methods.
```

read https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Drag/Drag.Move.js

if you want actual help, build an example on tinker.io or jsfiddle.net. if memory serves, this has been asked here before and there had to be some extra work around parsing possible droppables in addition to adding to the Collection.